# How can I get the data from fields of an .Include in a LINQ Query?

Tags: c#, linq

I am using Entity Framework 5 and I have these classes. What I want to do is to be able to get the data to populate the view listed below:

```
public partial class Subject
{
    public int SubjectId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Topic> Topics { get; set; }
}

public partial class Topic
{
    public int TopicId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int SubjectId { get; set; }
    public virtual Subject Subject { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SubTopic> SubTopics { get; set; }
}

public partial class SubTopic
{
    public int SubTopicId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int TopicId { get; set; }
    public virtual Topic Topic { get; set; }
}
```

Now I am trying to write a LINQ query to populate this class:

```
public class TopicSubTopicSelect
{
    public int TopicId { get; set; }
    public int SubTopicId { get; set; }
    public string TopicName { get; set; }
    public string SubTopicName { get; set; }
}
```

So far I have this:

```
        return _subjectsRepository
            .GetAll()
            .Where(s => s.SubjectId == subjectId)
            .Include(s => s.Topics.SelectMany(t => t.SubTopics))
            .AsEnumerable()
            .Select(item => new TopicSubTopicSelect(item.TopicId <<<
                                                    item.SubTopicId <<
                                                    item.Topic.Name <<
                                                    item.Name <<))
            .ToList();
```

Can someone tell me how I can get data from the fields I marked with <<. I tried to do .item.Topic.TopicId etc but that does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't start from Subject. You just start from SubTopic Repository, and you won't even need to use `.Include`. Do it like this:

```
_subTopicRepository
    .GetAll()
    .Where(s => s.Topic.SubjectId == subjectId)
    .Select(s => new TopicSubTopicSelect()
       {
          TopicId = s.TopidId,
          SubTopicId = s.SubTopicId,
          TopicName = s.Topic.Name,
          SubTopicName = s.Name
       })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Hopefully that `.GetAll()` is `IQueryable` not `IEnumerable`... and shouldn't SubTopicRepository have a `GetBySubjectId` method to encapsulate this query rather than exposing it?

Comment: The SubjectRepository should have a GetBySubjectId, not the SubTopicRepository.

Comment: Your example is using SubTopicRepository which is why I mentioned it - strictly speaking, that shouldn't even exist! Topic is the aggregate root, SubTopics don't make sense without a Topic so the entry point should always be Topic.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment on ataravati's answer, you shouldn't actually have a `SubTopicRepository` so you are correct in starting at `SubjectsRepository` however you are querying by the Subject ID so you shouldn't be going via `GetAll()`, you should have a `Get(int id)` method. The include should be handled as an implementation detail inside `Get` as the children (SubTopics) are part of the Subject. That makes the method call look like this instead:

```
return _subjectsRepository
        .Get(subjectId)
        .SelectMany(subject => subject.SubTopics))
        .Select(subTopic => new TopicSubTopicSelect
        {
            TopicId = subTopic.TopicId,
            SubTopicId = subTopic.SubTopicId,
            TopicName = subTopic.Topic.Name,
            SubTopicName = subTopic.Name
        }).ToList();
```